# Aligning Visio shape text to the top and to the left using Powershell

Tags: powershell, visio

I'm having problems with the second line below. How can I use PowerShell to align the shape text?

```
$squareshape.text = "abc";
$squareshape.align.top;
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using powershell?

Comment: Please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

> $squareshape.cells('VerticalAlign') = 0
>
> $squareshape.cells('Para.HorzAlign') = 0